# How to make text field compulsory only when the checkbox is checked with symfony annotation validations in model classes

Tags: validation, symfony

It is probably a very simple question but I've run out of juice here. `Vat` field is compulsory only when `isVatable` checkbox is check by user otherwise it can be ignored. How do I achieve this with group validation (annotations) in model class, not entity?

I checked [Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) and [Group Sequence](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) but to be honest didn't get my head around.

FormType

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = [])
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod($options['method'])
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->add('vat', 'text')
            ->add('isVatable', 'checkbox')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            ['data_class' => 'My\FrontendBundle\Model\UserModel']
        );
    }
}
```

ModelClass

```
class UserModel
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Vat is required only when checkbox is checked.")
     */
    protected $vat;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $isVatable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that the [`@Assert\True()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/True.html) constraint on a method usually works well for me for these sorts of validation scenario. You can add some validation constraints to methods as well as properties, which is pretty powerful.

The basic idea is that you can create a method, give it this annotation - if the method returns `true` the validation passes; if it returns `false` it fails.

```php
class UserModel
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $vat;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $isVatable = false;

    /**
     * @Assert\True(message="Please enter a VAT number")
     */
    public function isVatSetWhenIsVatableChecked()
    {
        // if this property is unchecked we don't
        // want to do any validation so return true
        if (!$this->isVatable) {
            return true;
        }

        // return true if $this->vat is not null
        // you might want to add some additional 
        // validation here to make sure the 
        return !is_null($this->vat);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can map the error message to a specific form field with the `error_mapping` option in your FormType object, as documented here:

http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1#error-mapping-fu

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You know what, I had a go with it before but failed because I had `@Assert` attached to `$vat` property of the model. Obviously that was the problem in my tests cos yours doesn't have it at all and works perfectly fine so thank you and +1

Comment: Nice example of using `@True` on method! I like it +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this in `...\Validator\Constraints`:

VAT.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

    class VAT extends Constraint

    {
        public $message = 'VAT is compulsory for applicable items';
        public $vat;
        public $isVatable;
    }
```

VATConstraint.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class VATValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        $data = $accessor->getValue($this->context->getRoot(), 'data');

        $vat = $data['vat'];
        $isVatable = $data['isVatable'];
        if ($isVatable && empty($vat)) {

            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

User model Entity:

```
use YourBundle\Validator\Constraints as MyAssert;

class UserModel
{
    /**
     * @MyAssert\NotBlank(message="Vat is required only when checkbox is checked.")
     */
    protected $vat;
...
}
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer cos it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator)

First make your Constraint class and your validatorClass:

```
<?php
// AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/NotBlankIfTaxEnabled.php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class NotBlankIfTaxEnabled extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'If isVat is enabled you have to enter a value in the Vat field.';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php
// AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/NotBlankIfTaxEnabledValidator.php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class NotBlankIfTaxEnabledValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($customer, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if($customer->getIsVatable() && strlen($customer->getVat()) == 0)
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    } 
}
```

Then add de classcontraint to your Entity/Model

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as AppAssert;

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @AppAssert\NotBlankIfTaxEnabled
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=64)
     *
     */
    private $vat;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="taxEnabled", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVatable;
```

and do not forget to switch off the required attribute for both fields in your formType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('vat', NULL, array('required' => FALSE))
            ->add('isVatable', NULL, array('required' => FALSE))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customer'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_customer';
    }
}
```

Comment: I used them before but unfortunately it is a bit over-kill for this very simple process however thank you for the answer and effort.

Comment: Of course that is possible. Thank you for your reply, i appreciate it.